# How to provide a user defined delegate with out parameters in Microsoft Moles

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moles

I wanted to bypass an internal method call and hence have mocked it. The mocked method delegate looks like:

```
public Microsoft.Moles.Framework.MolesDelegates.OutOutFunc<string,string,string,
byte[]> GetlineStringStringOutStringOut { set; }
```

Now, in my test when I try to access this mocked method like:

```
GetlineStringStringOutStringOut = (a,b,c) => {return bytearray};
```

an error occurs saying parameter 2 and 3 must be declared with out keyword but when I declare them with out keyword it's doesn't compile at all. I read other SO questions and answers and it seems it can't be done.

Is it possible to provide user defined delegate for this? If yes, please give an example.

**EDIT:**

I tried to declare my own delegate of same signature as mocked delegate

```
static delegate byte[] MyFunc<String, String, String>
(string a, out string b, out string c);
```

but I'm not sure how can I call this while calling the mocked delegate method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to assign values to `b` and `c` variables before returning from your lambda and also specify the parameters types explicitly, something like this:

```
GetlineStringStringOutStringOut = (string a, out string b, out string c) => 
{ 
    b = c = string.Empty;

    return new byte[] { };
};
```